# Issue in Bottom Sheet snap point calculation for all devices

Tags: react-native

I'm calculating snap points for [React Native Bottom Sheet](https://gorhom.github.io/react-native-bottom-sheet) and facing an issue in Android devices. The calculation doesn't work universally to find `sheetEndSnap`. The `StatusBar.currentHeight` value needs to be considered for some devices. For others, it does not need to be considered. I can't figure out what is causing this issue and how to differentiate the `sheetEndSnap` calculation based on devices.

[image]

The current implementation is like this.

```
import React, {useMemo, useRef} from 'react';
import {Dimensions, View, StatusBar, Platform} from 'react-native';
import BottomSheet from '@gorhom/bottom-sheet';
import {useSafeAreaInsets} from 'react-native-safe-area-context';

const {height: windowHeight} = Dimensions.get('window');
const statusBarHeight = Platform.OS === 'android' ? StatusBar.currentHeight : 0;

const sheetStartSnap = 200;

const Screen = () => {
    const {top, bottom} = useSafeAreaInsets();
    const ref = useRef < BottomSheet > null;

    const sheetEndSnap = windowHeight - (top + bottom + statusBarHeight); // For some devices this works fine
    // const sheetEndSnap = windowHeight - (top + bottom); // For other devices this works fine
    const snapPoints = useMemo(() => [sheetStartSnap, sheetEndSnap], [sheetEndSnap]);

    return (
        <View style={{flex: 1}}>
            <BottomSheet ref={ref} index={0} snapPoints={snapPoints}>
                <View style={{flex: 1}} />
            </BottomSheet>
        </View>
    );
};
```